# How can you enter a table and column name into another table with their row contents?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to make a table that shows changes in a database with the following format:

| TableName | ColumnName | OldValue | NewValue | RowID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company | CompName | ABC | XYZ | 1 |
| Company | Address | 123 | 456 | 1 |
| Company | CompName | EDF | TRQ | 2 |

This is all in Microsoft SQL Server, and want to try and use the system tables to connect with the data using triggers as the data is updated (using Magic Tables to capture the old/new value as it is changed).
I just don't know how to connect the table and column information with the row data to get it to display in this format.

So far I have been able to find the system tables and get them to show their updates, and the regular tables with their updates, but have not had success in figuring out how to connect them together.

Comment: I'm not clear what system tables you're referring to. Can you name them? Are they part of Magic Tables or actually provided by SQL Server?

Comment: This is honestly the first time I've heard the `inserted`/`deleted` tables referred to as "magic" tables.

Comment: So I am currently trying to use these columns and connect the row data from the table and column that is updated.
SELECT T.TABLE_NAME, C.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
 INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T ON T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME

Comment: Would you not, perhaps, be better off using something like a temporal table, rather than this denormalised approach?

Comment: System_Versioning is part of the SQL Standard and supported by many RDBMS, including SQL Server since 2016 - it would make sense to use it for tracking change history.